# Why does the Scala compiler say that copy is not a member of my case class?

Tags: scala, copy, case-class

First, this is in Scala 2.8, so it should be there! =)

I'm working on Lift's Javascript objects and I want to have the following:

```
case class JsVar(varName: String, andThen: String*) extends JsExp {
  // ...
  def -&(right: String) = copy(andThen=(right :: andThen.toList.reverse).reverse :_*)
}
```

Unfortunately, I get the following compiler error:

```
[error] Lift/framework/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCommands.scala:452: not found: value copy
[error]     def -&(right: String) = copy(andThen=(right :: andThen.toList.reverse).reverse :_*)
[error]
```

The case class has properties, so there should be a `copy` method, right?

If I try `this.copy` I get practically the same error:

```
[error] Lift/framework/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/http/js/JsCommands.scala:452: value copy is not a member of net.liftweb.http.js.JE.JsVar
[error]     def -&(right: String) = this.copy(andThen=(right :: andThen.toList.reverse).reverse :_*)
[error]
```

Why is this and how can I use `copy` in my case class method? Or is the idea that `copy` is something the compiler adds after declaring my methods?

Should I just do this?

```
case class JsVar(varName: String, andThen: String*) extends JsExp {
  // ...
  def -&(right: String) = JsVar(varName, (right :: andThen.toList.reverse).reverse :_*)
}
```

Comment: This seems to be related to the vararg parameter ... without checking the bug tracker or the spec, this feels like a bug.

Comment: Is JsExp already a case class? If so this might be related to know issues with case class inheritance.

Comment: No, it's a (rather big) trait that extends two simple traits.

Comment: Simplified problem, on 2.9.0.1: `scala> case class Foo(xs: Int*) {
     def bar = copy(xs = List(1, 2, 3): _*) }
<console>:8: error: not found: value copy
       def bar = copy(xs = List(1, 2, 3): _*) }`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The specification is silent on this regard, but this is actually expected. The `copy` method depends on default parameters, and default parameters are not allowed for repeated paramters (varargs):

> It is not allowed to deﬁne any default
>   arguments in a parameter section with
>   a repeated parameter.

(Scala Reference, section 4.6.2 - Repeated Parameters)

```
scala> def f(xs: Int*) = xs
f: (xs: Int*)Int*

scala> def f(xs: Int* = List(1, 2, 3)) = xs
<console>:24: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[Int]
 required: Int*
       def f(xs: Int* = List(1, 2, 3)) = xs
                            ^
<console>:24: error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments
       def f(xs: Int* = List(1, 2, 3)) = xs
           ^
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks. Why couldn't you have a default value for repeated parameters, though? Is there some magic going on? I notice that with `case class A(b: String*)`, `A("a", "b")` and `A(List("a", "b") :_*)` have different signatures.

Comment: @pr1001 No clue. You may wish to read the SID (SIP?) about default and named parameters, as it may remark the reason for that restriction.